# How can I display images from s3 urls on Odoo without storing them

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, odoo

I want to display my product images from amazon s3 bucket without saving it in base64 format in odoo. Is it possible to achieve this?

Right now this code in odoo base generates the local url:

```
var FieldBinaryImage = AbstractFieldBinary.extend({
_getImageUrl: function (model, res_id, field, unique) {
        var url = session.url('/web/image', {
            model: model,
            id: JSON.stringify(res_id),
            field: field,
            // unique forces a reload of the image when the record has been updated
            unique: field_utils.format.datetime(unique).replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''),
        });
        console.log("base_url", url)
        return url
    },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use image_url which will be used to compute image. Only url gets stored not the image.
Add this in your model

```
image = fields.Binary(string="Image", compute='_compute_image_url')
image_url = fields.Char(string='Image URL')

@api.depends('image_url')
def _compute_image_url(self):
    """ function to load image from URL """
    image = False
    if self.image_url:
        image = base64.b64encode(requests.get(self.image_url).content)
    self.image = image
```

Hope this is what you looking for